# asynchronous thread pool with ordered completion

Tags: c++, multithreading

In a basic thread pool pattern, the main thread pushes up tasks to a request queue. The thread pool performs the tasks in an unspecified order, and posts notifications to the main event loop whenever each task is completed.

In some cases, you benefit from the additional throughput, but you can only use the finished tasks in a specified order. Let's say you have an audio application. The main thread sends chunks of audio to be processed by the thread pool. Several chunks may be processed concurrently and completed out of order, but the main thread must push each processed chunk to the audio stream in the order it was submitted to be processed.

My first thought is to use some kind of a thread-safe queue (linked list or deque) of requested tasks, and have the main thread wait on a "completed" flag at the head of the queue, and then unlink it and make use of the data. On further thought, it occurred to me that this problem must have been solved many times already. How is this usually done in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look boost::io_service for your thread pool problem. its easy to use and implement.

[boost asynchronous io service](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html)

---

Edited:

You can solve this joining problem using std::async and std::future in C++11. Simplest way to do this may be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <future>

template <typename RAIter>
int parallel_sum(RAIter beg, RAIter end)
{
  auto len = end - beg;
  if (len < 1000)
    return std::accumulate(beg, end, 0);

  RAIter mid = beg + len/2;
  auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async,
                           parallel_sum<RAIter>, mid, end);
  int sum = parallel_sum(beg, mid);
  return sum + handle.get();
}
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v(10000, 1);
  std::cout << "The sum is " << parallel_sum(v.begin(), v.end()) << '\n';
}
```

**handle.get()** return std::future object synchronously so your parallel_sum executes with multiple threads and returns result by ordered thread joining. So by changing this example you may process your audio data with parallel chunks and return final result in ordered.

std::async explanation and original example [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

Comment: As far as I can tell boost::io_service allows serialized _execution_ (through the strand mechanism), which is not what I am looking for. I am looking for asynchronous execution, but serialized completion notification.

Comment: then i can say you need to look over std::async and future in C++11 (**you can aslo use booost::future as prerequisite of ur application**) templates for ur case. 
[C++11 way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) You can look this example and change it as you need to be. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: C++11 std::async would also be my suggestion but the algorithms for synchronisation are even experimental in [C++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/when_all)

Comment: Thanks, looks like std::async will be a good first step. On top of that, I could have a std::deque into which the std::future's are pushed in order, and a secondary thread with a loop calling get() on the head of the queue, handling it appropriately, and then popping it.

Answer (score 1):

We have a GNU licensed [runloop](https://github.com/Corvusoft/runloop) in use across many a server application. Perhaps it would be a suitable fit?

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <corvusoft/core/run_loop.hpp>

using namespace std;
using corvusoft::core::RunLoop;

int main( const int, const char** )
{
    const auto task = [ ]( void ) { return error_code( ); };

    auto runloop = make_shared< RunLoop >( );
    runloop->launch( task );
    runloop->launch( task );
    runloop->launch( task );
    runloop->launch( [ runloop ]( void )
    {
        runloop->wait( ); //wait for other tasks to complete.

        //perform additional logic with the computed result.

        runloop->stop( ); //causes start to return.
        return error_code( );
    } );

    runloop->start( );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't do it. I want to be able to get the completed tasks in the order submitted, not just run them asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common ways are using either OpenMP or MPI implementations. I assume your threads will share data (the audio file(s)) so you'll need to learn OpenMP.

A good place to start is here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/

Comment: Which particular OpenMP API? I was thinking more like something built on std::thread or such.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by which, but I have done a project with openMP before if you want to check out PreyPredatorOpenMP.cpp here: [link](https://github.com/b-bitar/Real-Time-Multiprocessing/tree/master/PreyPredatorOpenMP/PreyPredatorOpenMP)

You will mainly need to add these 2 lines before the computationally heavy for loop and the scheduler will decide how to separate the tasks among the threads:

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(numOfThreads)

#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)

Comment: part III might help you grasp some OpenMP concepts and has a comparison of different scheduling implementations (static,dynamic, guided,auto) [link](https://www.basselbitar.me/prey-predator-multiprocessing-game/)

Comment: That isn't what I am looking for. OpenMP can schedule asynchronous tasks, as can many other APIs. I am looking specifically at the problem of ordering the notifications for completed tasks. I would rather find a solution using existing C++ constructs rather than bring in an entire large library such as OpenMP.